# Can't see the 3D rendered mode in Blender 2.81

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

So, I'm new with blender and I am having problems on what's happening cause I can't see the 3D render mode. I attached the sc. Thanks ;-;[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Which render engine are are you using?

Comment: Hi! I'm using eevee in rendering. It was working earlier but all of a sudden it's gone :'(

Comment: Can you render the scene in cycles? If yes, then there must be some problem with the EEVEE renderer. Send the blend file, can you?